# Formatting JSON response

Tags: java, android, json

This is the JSON response I am getting using Foursquare API. Here, I am able to extract names of different venues using "name" tag and display as listview. But, the issue is I am not able to extract data from "location" tag given in JSON response.

This is how I am getting names of venues:

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                    jsonResponse = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    cinemas = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);//response

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < cinemas.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject venueObject = cinemas.getJSONObject(i);
                        //   String id = venueObject.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = venueObject.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        prgmName.add(name);
                       }
```

JSON response:

```
{
"response": {
    "venues": [
        {
            "referralId": "v1404154392",
            "id": "52cd70b711d279a93b2761ac",
            "location": {
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "",
                    "India"
                ],
                "distance": 635,
                "lng": 70.79618019123747,
                "cc": "IN",
                "lat": 22.302471281197825,
                "country": "India"
            },
            "stats": {
                "checkinsCount": 24,
                "tipCount": 0,
                "usersCount": 14
            },
            "verified": false,
            "name": "R WORLD BIG CINEMA",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d180941735",
                    "icon": {
                        "suffix": ".png",
                        "prefix": "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/movietheater_"
                    },
                    "shortName": "Cineplex",
                    "pluralName": "Multiplexes",
                    "primary": true,
                    "name": "Multiplex"
                }
            ],
            "hereNow": {
                "summary": "0 people here",
                "count": 0,
                "groups": []
            },
            "contact": {},
            "specials": {
                "count": 0,
                "items": []
            }
        }
    ]
},
"meta": {
    "code": 200
}
```

}

Any help in this regard will be great.

Comment: what data do you want from location tag

Comment: Formatting JOSN use http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: I want "lat" and "lng" from it

Comment: Please change title of question to match the question. You are not trying to format JSON, you are trying to access a nested JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getJSONObject again on`venueObject`:

Try this for example:

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json.toString());
jsonResponse = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
// products found
// Getting Array of Products
cinemas = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);//response

// looping through All Products
for (int i = 0; i < cinemas.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject venueObject = cinemas.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = venueObject.getString(TAG_NAME);
    JSONObject location = venueObject. getJSONObject(TAG_LOCATION);
    String countryCode = location.getString("cc");

    prgmName.add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
        objMain = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONObject objRes=objMain.getJSONObject("response");

        JSONArray arrVenues=objRes.getJSONArray("venues");

        JSONObject obj=arrVenues.getJSONObject(0);

        JSONObject objLocation=obj.getJSONObject("location");

        Double lat=objLocation.getDouble("lat");

        Double lnt=objLocation.getDouble("lng");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

location is an json object again in the results array so you have to modify your code:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < cinemas.length(); i++) 
   {
    JSONObject venueObject = cinemas.getJSONObject(i);

    String name = venueObject.getString(TAG_NAME);

    JSONObject find_location=venueObject.getJSONObject("location");

      String lat = find_location.getString("lat");

      String lon = find_location.getString("lng");

    prgmName.add(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json.toString());
      jsonResponse = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");

      cinemas = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);//response


      for (int i = 0; i < cinemas.length(); i++)
      {
            JSONObject venue = cinemas.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = venue.getString(TAG_NAME);
            JSONObject loc = venue. getJSONObject(TAG_LOCATION);
            String countryCode = location.getString(3);

            String lat = loc.getString("lat");

            String lon = loc.getString("lng");

            prgmName.add(name);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String jsonStr ="{\"response\":{\"venues\":[{\"referralId\":\"v1404154392\",\"id\":\"52cd70b711d279a93b2761ac\",\"location\":{\"formattedAddress\":[\"\",\"India\"],\"distance\":635,\"lng\":70.79618019123747,\"cc\":\"IN\",\"lat\":22.302471281197825,\"country\":\"India\"},\"stats\":{\"checkinsCount\":24,\"tipCount\":0,\"usersCount\":14},\"verified\":false,\"name\":\"R WORLD BIG CINEMA\",\"categories\":[{\"id\":\"4bf58dd8d48988d180941735\",\"icon\":{\"suffix\":\".png\",\"prefix\":\"https:\\/\\/ss1.4sqi.net\\/img\\/categories_v2\\/arts_entertainment\\/movietheater_\"},\"shortName\":\"Cineplex\",\"pluralName\":\"Multiplexes\",\"primary\":true,\"name\":\"Multiplex\"}],\"hereNow\":{\"summary\":\"0 people here\",\"count\":0,\"groups\":[]},\"contact\":{},\"specials\":{\"count\":0,\"items\":[]}}]},\"meta\":{\"code\":200}}";
try {
    JSONObject respone = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    String code = respone.getJSONObject("meta").getString("code");

    JSONArray jsonArr = respone.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("venues");

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
         HashMap<String, Object> venueMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         venueMap.put("referralId", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("referralId"));
         venueMap.put("id", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
         venueMap.put("verified", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("verified"));
         venueMap.put("name", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));

         HashMap<String,Object> locationMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         locationMap.put("distance", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("distance"));
         locationMap.put("lng", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("lng"));
         locationMap.put("cc", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("cc"));
         locationMap.put("lat", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("lat"));
         locationMap.put("country", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("country"));
         ArrayList<String> formattedAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();

         JSONArray formattedAddressJsonArray = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getJSONArray("formattedAddress");

         for(int j=0;j<formattedAddressJsonArray.length();j++){
            formattedAddressList.add(formattedAddressJsonArray.getString(j));
         }
         locationMap.put("formattedAddress",formattedAddressList);
         venueMap.put("location",locationMap);

         HashMap<String,Object> statsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         statsMap.put("distance", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("stats").getString("checkinsCount"));
         statsMap.put("tipCount", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("stats").getString("tipCount"));
         statsMap.put("usersCount", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("stats").getString("usersCount"));

         venueMap.put("stats",statsMap);

         ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> categoriesList =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
         JSONArray categoriesJsonArray = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories");

         for(int j=0;j<categoriesJsonArray.length();j++) {
             HashMap<String, Object> categoryMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             categoryMap.put("id", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
             categoryMap.put("shortName", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("shortName"));
             HashMap<String,String> iconMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
             iconMap.put("suffix", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("icon").getString("suffix"));
             iconMap.put("prefix", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("icon").getString("prefix"));
             categoryMap.put("icon", iconMap);
             categoryMap.put("pluralName", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("pluralName"));
             categoryMap.put("primary", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("primary"));
             categoryMap.put("name", categoriesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));
             categoriesList.add(categoryMap);
         }

         venueMap.put("categories",categoriesList);

         HashMap<String,Object> hereNowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         hereNowMap.put("summary", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("hereNow").getString("summary"));
         hereNowMap.put("count", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("hereNow").getString("count"));

         ArrayList<String> groupsList = new ArrayList<String>();

         JSONArray groupsJsonArray = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("hereNow").getJSONArray("groups");
         for(int j=0;j<groupsJsonArray.length();j++){
             groupsList.add(groupsJsonArray.getString(j));
         }

         hereNowMap.put("groups",groupsList);
         venueMap.put("hereNow",hereNowMap);

         JSONObject  contact = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("contact");

         HashMap<String,Object> specialsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         specialsMap.put("count", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("specials").getString("count"));
         ArrayList<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();

         JSONArray itemsJsonArray = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("specials").getJSONArray("items");
         for(int j=0;j<itemsJsonArray.length();j++){
             itemsList.add(itemsJsonArray.getString(j));
         }

         specialsMap.put("items",itemsList);
         venueMap.put("specials",specialsMap);
         list.add(venueMap);
    }

    System.out.print("Code: " + code);
    for (HashMap<String,Object> venue : list){
         System.out.print("referralId : " + venue.get("referralId"));
         System.out.print("id : " + venue.get("id"));
         System.out.print("verified : " + venue.get("verified"));
         System.out.print("name : " + venue.get("name"));
         HashMap<String,Object> locationMap = (HashMap<String,Object>)venue.get("location");
         System.out.print("distance : " + locationMap.get("distance"));
         System.out.print("lng : " + locationMap.get("lng"));
         System.out.print("cc : " + locationMap.get("cc"));
         System.out.print("lat : " + locationMap.get("lat"));
         System.out.print("country : " + locationMap.get("country"));

         ArrayList<String> formattedAddressList = (ArrayList<String>) locationMap.get("formattedAddress");
         for (String formattedAddress : formattedAddressList){
              System.out.print("formattedAddress : " +formattedAddress);
         }

         HashMap<String,Object> statsMap = (HashMap<String,Object>)venue.get("stats");
         System.out.print("distance : " + statsMap.get("distance"));
         System.out.print("tipCount : " + statsMap.get("lng"));
         System.out.print("usersCount : " + statsMap.get("cc"));
         ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> categoriesList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>)venue.get("categories");
         for (HashMap<String,Object> category : categoriesList){
              System.out.print("id : " + category.get("id"));
              System.out.print("shortName : " + category.get("shortName"));
              System.out.print("shortName : " + category.get("shortName"));
              HashMap<String,Object> icon = (HashMap<String,Object>)category.get("icon");
              System.out.print("icon suffix: " + icon.get("suffix"));
              System.out.print("icon prefix: " + icon.get("prefix"));
              System.out.print("pluralName : " + category.get("pluralName"));
              System.out.print("primary : " + category.get("primary"));
              System.out.print("name : " + category.get("name"));
         }

         HashMap<String,Object> hereNowMap = (HashMap<String,Object>)venue.get("hereNow");
         System.out.print("summary : " + hereNowMap.get("summary"));
         System.out.print("count : " + hereNowMap.get("count"));
         ArrayList<String> groupsList = (ArrayList<String>) hereNowMap.get("groups");
         for (String group : groupsList){
              System.out.print("group : " +group);
         }
         HashMap<String,Object> specialsMap = (HashMap<String,Object>)venue.get("specials");
         System.out.print("count : " + specialsMap.get("summary"));

         ArrayList<String> itemsList = (ArrayList<String>) specialsMap.get("items");
         for (String item : itemsList){
              System.out.print("item : " +item);
         }

  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```